# Run a GitLab CI/CD Pipeline on a group-based Level

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, cicd

I really don't know if this is possible and a first search didn't help me.

Currently i have a CI/CD Script that publish a npm-Package to a private npm-Registry and afterwards generates A Confluence-Documentation out of an Ascii-Doc Root-Folder in the Repository.

And we will have a lot of Repositories that will use this exact CI/CD-Script and all those Repos will be in the same group. So is there a way to define a single CI/CD Script for every repo in the Group in GitLab, so i can reduce redundancies?

I know i can just put the script in the repos itself but this feels repetitive and if i need to change the script i need to do this for every single one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, thats possible. I am doing exactly the same in my projects, where I have a bunch of projects which all need to build in the same manner.

I have create a common project in the group which just holds the common .gitlab-ci.yml file.

Then go to each of my target projects under `"Settings->CI/CD->General Pipelines"` and mention the path to the common .gitlab-ci.yml in the `"CI/CD configuration file"`

refer to the screenshot.

The path here should be the absolute path to your .gitlab-ci.yml without your on-prem domain name or gitlab.com whichever way you are hosting the service.

for example

if my common project where my .gitlab-ci.yml files has the following path

https://gitlab.com/myrandomgroup1/myrandomgroup2/mycommonproject

then the values in `"CI/CD configuration file"` should be specified as

```
.gitlab-ci.yml@myrandomgroup1/myrandomgroup2/mycommonproject
```

in each of my other target project `"Settings->CI/CD->General Pipelines"` settings

So in this way the other target project wont have any .gitlab-ci.yml of their own but will use the common one specified above

[image]