# Injecting a gitlab CI/CD pipeline at a group level

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

Currently, I'm using required pipeline configuration to "inject" a pipeline to all projects in a top-level group and sub-groups. This would allow me to run my pipeline first than run the pipeline at the local project level.

However, required pipeline configuration is [deprecated in v15.9 and will be removed in v17.0](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/continuous_integration.html#:%7E:text=Required%20pipeline%20configuration,-Version%20history&text=This%20feature%20was%20deprecated%20in,projects%20on%20a%20GitLab%20instance).

I understand that I can switch to compliance framework/pipeline. But I would need to manually make changes to each and every projects (Have tens of thousands) in the top-level groups and subgroups. And there is a possibility that new projects might be left out.

The schema of the groups looked something like this:

**Top-level-Group**
|--*Subgroup1*
|----Project1
|----Project2
|----*Sub-Subgroup1*
|------Project3
|--*Subgroup2*
|----Project2

I know there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76978816/run-a-gitlab-ci-cd-pipeline-on-a-group-based-level) on this previously. But the solution requires me to go to each and every project to include the "general CI/CD configuration file", which is very tedious and the possibility to miss out new projects is high.

I want to be able to run my pipeline (not necessary in gitlab) for all projects in the top-level group and subgroups than continue whatever local pipeline is configured for the projects.

Appreciate if anyone can provide any insights or recommendations. Currently, I have no idea on where/how to start.

Comment: There is no way out. You need to align with the direction where the gitlab product is moving, by adopting the compliance pipeline framework. In such large setups of 10K jobs, you can create the topmost template as the library and ask each team to consume it as a first stage of the pipeline. You need not be the one making the change in all 10K jobs

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Centralizing this process would actually remove the monitoring process that needs to perform to ensure that each team/project is complying.

I was wondering if it was possible to run my pipeline outside of gitlab (say aws codepipeline or some 3rd party service) via webhooks? Once done, run a gitlab runner script to trigger the local pipelines in necessary. (Of course, the 3rd party service must be able to pull codes from gitlab)

I know that i can set up group webhooks.

Comment: Essentially to perfom such an action you need to `clone` the repo. Thats why it is easier to democratize the process (its 2024, centralize is not the right word!) although it calls for a culture change within your developer community.
However, coming to your requirment, I would suggest creating a python based Gitlab API automation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html . You can query all the ssh repo URLs, clone it to a local host, run your pipeline against each repo in parallel execution method. Parse the results and send notifications as required.

Comment: please provide what action was taken and mark this ticket accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround for my problem using out-of-band solution.

Basically, i use a group web hook to trigger a lambda function in aws which in turn will trigger the pipeline that i want to run in gitlab.

This ensures that i'm still using the same runners as previously.

Group Webhook -> AWS lambda -> trigger pipeline thru API

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the question (running a pipeline at the group level), for that I have no answer.

Instead, I can make the correct approach (switching to the new compliance framework) significantly easier using automation.  I had recently stepped into something similar where I had to delete hundreds of thousands of pipelines during a massive corporate reorg.  Fortunately, GitLab supports a CLI tool called [glab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/editor_extensions/gitlab_cli/) which is capable of arbitrary API calls (and even has a bunch of convenience verbs for common things like cloning or creating MRs).

In my case, I was able to generate a one-liner which would walk across all of the enumerated projects (you can also get a project list via the API; I only wanted to touch specific projects).  In my case, this looked something like:

```bash
for proj in <proj_ids>; do for repo in $(glab api /projects/$proj/registry/repositories | jq '.[].id'); do glab api /projects/$proj/registry/repositories/$repo -X DELETE; done; done
```

The GitLab API responses are in JSON so this also uses `jq` but there should be no other dependencies.  You will obviously need to heavily tweak this based on your specific need; the above is only as an example.

Comment: It looks like `glab` will reside on the host of Gitlab itself, this is certainly one way of achieving what the OP has specified. However, in your case, did you have to clone a 1000 repos, add/modify the `gitlab-ci.yml` to run the pipeline with your requiement? (While still not modifying the gitlab-ci.yml contents of the developers)

Comment: glab runs on the local host CLI.  The idea is to migrate the repos to the new setup once and be done with it rather than carry this maintenance cost forever.  Also, If the need is to manipulate the internal state of the repo, then only a commit will do that and so a clone is necessary.  What the above does is allow a script to be written which will just rip across all of the repos and clone / modify / commit (or whatever) without human intervention.

Comment: Also, to address the "new repo" problem where including the common config is forgotten, I highly recommend setting up a repo template with all of the required settings.  Then the devs just create a new project from the template and everything "just works".  Even if some other approach is to be used, I would still recommend this as it makes the correct answer the easiest one ("just click a button and you get a working build!").  Finally, if you really want to, glab could also be used to create an audit script if you wanted to verify this stuff on a regular interval.